# html tag in php variables

Tags: php, html

given a php variable

```
$a="<b>hello</b>";
echo $a;
//prints <b>hello<b>
```

But I want it to print hello in bold with the formatting.
Please tell me what I should do...

Comment: Print to where? The command line?

Comment: `echo "a"` should really be `echo $a`

Comment: What seems to be the problem, officer?

Comment: now the output ist right. but what about the rest of the source? without <html><head></head><body><?php //your code here?></body></html> there might be some browser that don't interpret it that well and don't apply the <b> </b> because they are missing the <html> and <body> tags

Comment: I have rest of code html,head,body everything.. this part is enclosed within php tags...

Comment: i want a php variable containing html tags to be able to print with formatting when i echo it...

Comment: Again, where are you printing it *to*?

Comment: Question is difficult to understand due to incomplete information. OP has not been able to clarify. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<b>" . $a . "</b>";
```

oh, you edited your code. what you have should work.